# Unable to fetch response for login functionality

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, api, axios

```
 const AUTH = () => {
    const params = JSON.stringify({
      user: {
        user_type: 'customer',
        mobile: '8349222680',
        password: '12345',
      },
    });
    const url = 'https://salon-host-dev.herokuapp.com/api/v1/logins/';
    axios
      .post(url, {
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          data: 'data=' + JSON.stringify(params),
        }),
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log('--->', response.status);
      });
  };
```

I am trying to get response from url but unable to that if Params passed in raw body json in postman then i am geeting expected response but not in following code please help

Comment: did it like this body:params but its not giving unhandle promice rejection 1

Comment: just giving network error only

Comment: {
   "user":{
    "user_type":"customer",
        "mobile":"8349222680",
        "password":"12345"
    }
}

Comment: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Network Error

Comment: oh ... wait ... react native ... forget all I said, removing all my comments

Comment: what should i do sir please help me

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for axios post request is below

```
axios.post(url, params, 
{headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}})
.then()
```

The header should be the 3rd argument to the POST method.

Comment: What did you mean by this multiple stringify at front end? Also in postman you just sent it as an object without any modifications. Is it possible to see your server code

Comment: Answer has been edited.

Comment: still its giving unhandle promice rejection

Answer (score 0):

`axios` (and `axios.post` for that matter) can be called like `axios.post(config)` `axios.post(url[, config])` `axios.post(url[, data [, config]])` .... so you've chosen the second pattern,

the data to send is in `data` property, NOT the `body` property -

also you DONT need to send JSON, you can send the object

So given

```
const params = {
  user: {
    user_type: 'customer',
    mobile: '8349222680',
    password: '12345',
  },
};
const url = 'https://salon-host-dev.herokuapp.com/api/v1/logins/';
```

You can

```
axios.post({
  url: url,
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
  },
  data: params,
})
```

or

```
axios.post(url, {
  headers: {
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  },
  data: params,
})
```

or

```
axios.post(url, params, {
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
  }
})
```

---

Additionally, if you rename params to data

```
const data = {
  user: {
    user_type: 'customer',
    mobile: '8349222680',
    password: '12345',
  },
};
```

and create a headers variable

```
const headers = {
  'content-type': 'application/json',
};
```

you can do any of the following

```
axios.post(url, data, { headers });
axios.post(url, {data, headers});
axios.post({url, data, headers});
```